# Show long text in div tag

Tags: html, css

if I write long text in div, the long text exceed div wall. 
how can I show it as multi line?

My test Code is below

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="left: 700px; top: 150px; width: 400px; height: 360px; border:1px solid">1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CSS `word-wrap` property:

```
div {
     word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to analyze the content and decide on permissible line breaking points. In your question, the content is a string of digits. Can it be broken after any digit, or after every three digits, or how? The real content is probably something different and might have permissible breaking points depending on its type. For example, there are rules for breaking URLs, and there are rules for breaking mathematical expressions, and there are rules for breaking texts in languages that don’t use spaces between words.

Once you know where you wish to allow breaks, the most robust way is to insert the `<wbr>` tag at every allowed break point. The standards-conforming way, which works almost as widely nowadays, is to insert the ZERO-WIDTH SPACE character, e.g. using the character reference `&#x200b;`. More info: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html#suggest

In the very special case where any point is an allowable break point, the CSS declaration `word-wrap: break-word` can be used: it is compact, and it works on modern browsers (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=wordwrap on support).

Answer (score 0):

If there are no space characters you can't use word-wrap so you can't do it!!!

Comment: the break-word setting does what it says, it breaks the word even if there are no spaces http://www.css3.info/preview/word-wrap/